# Google Search Console flagging certain events as invalid

Tags: civievent, drupal

Recently I checked my Drupal 7 site (CiviCRM 5.48.2) on Google Search Console and noticed that there were 12 pages listed as invalid. They all had the same two errors: 'Missing field "fn" (in "hcalendar#location")' and 'Missing field "dtstart"'. All of them are event pages, 10 are events which have been completed and two are ongoing with no particular start or end date.
Google flags this code (snippet):

[image]

Google states: "Warning: When the event status changes, DON'T remove the startDate. The startDate property is required to help identify the unique event." and "DO NOT put the name of the event location. Instead, use location.name to specify the name of the location where the event is being held."

How can I correct these errors?